# Modify SQL trigger to work when inserted table contains more than one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, triggers

I've got a SQL trigger written for a table in SQL Server 2008. It works well when there is only one row in the 'inserted' table. How can I modify this trigger to work correctly when there are multiple rows? Performance is key here, so I'd like to stay away from cursors, temp tables, etc. (if possible).

Essentially the trigger checks to see if either the 'ClientID' or 'TemplateID' fields were changed. If they were, and the OriginalClientID or OriginalTemplateID fields are null, it populates them (thus setting the OriginalXXX fields once and only once so I can always see what the first values were).

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trigSetOriginalValues]
   ON  [dbo].[Review]
   FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    IF (NOT UPDATE(TemplateID) AND NOT UPDATE(ClientID)) return

    DECLARE @TemplateID int
    DECLARE @OriginalTemplateID int
    DECLARE @ClientID int
    DECLARE @OriginalClientID int   
    DECLARE @ReviewID int

    SET @ReviewID = (SELECT ReviewID FROM inserted)
    SET @ClientID = (SELECT ClientID FROM inserted)
    SET @TemplateID = (SELECT TemplateID FROM inserted)
    SET @OriginalTemplateID = (SELECT OriginalTemplateID FROM inserted);
    SET @OriginalClientID = (SELECT OriginalClientID FROM inserted);

    IF (@OriginalTemplateID IS NULL AND @TemplateID IS NOT NULL) 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[Review] SET OriginalTemplateID = @TemplateID WHERE ReviewID=@ReviewID
    END

    IF (@OriginalClientID IS NULL AND @ClientID IS NOT NULL) 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[Review] SET OriginalClientID = @ClientID WHERE ReviewID=@ReviewID
    END 
END
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be your trigger:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.OriginalTemplateID = B.TemplateID
FROM [dbo].[Review] A
INNER JOIN INSERTED B
    ON A.ReviewID = B.ReviewID
WHERE A.OriginalTemplateID IS NULL AND B.TemplateID IS NOT NULL

UPDATE A
SET A.OriginalClientID = B.ClientID 
FROM [dbo].[Review] A
INNER JOIN INSERTED B
    ON A.ReviewID = B.ReviewID
WHERE A.OriginalClientID IS NULL AND B.ClientID IS NOT NULL
```

Though you could still do this on a single `UPDATE`, but with a more complicated filter.